# Google Cloud Storage download url no more valid

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

In my swift app, I am uploading some files in GCS in a not public bucket.

Then I fetch downloadURL and save it.

It works fine for a lot of files but for an unknown reason, some download URLs do not work.

I get this when trying to download file using Safari:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Firebase App Check token is invalid."
  }
}
```

I enabled AppCheck for my App.

Do you know what could cause that?
I understand that Token is invalid but I don't what could have caused that.

Here is my function which upload file, pretty simple:

```
public func putFile(teamFolderName: String, url: URL, filename: String, metadata: StorageMetadata?, completion: @escaping (URL?, Error?)->(Void)) -> StorageUploadTask {
        
        Console.sharedInstance.log.info("Uploading file \(filename) to team folder: \(teamFolderName)")
        
        let fileRef = getTeamStorageReference(for: teamFolderName).child("\(filename)")
        
        let uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(from: url, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            guard let _ = metadata else {
                completion(nil,error)
                return
            }
            
            fileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                completion(url,error)
                return
            }
        })
        
        return uploadTask
    }
```

I found a workaround by checking if file is reachable using HEAD http method. If not I reupload it then ask again for downloadURL.

It works but I don't knonw why sometines downloadURL is invalid.

Here is my updated code:

```
public func putFile(teamFolderName: String, url: URL, filename: String, metadata: StorageMetadata?, completion: @escaping (URL?, Error?)->(Void)) -> StorageUploadTask {
            
        Console.sharedInstance.log.info("Uploading file \(filename) to team folder: \(teamFolderName)")
        
        let fileRef = getTeamStorageReference(for: teamFolderName).child("\(filename)")
        
        let uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(from: url, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            guard let _ = metadata else {
                Async.main {
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
                return
            }
            
            fileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
                guard let downloadURL = url else {
                    Async.main {
                        completion(nil, error)
                    }
                    return
                }
                
                // Check if the download URL is reachable
                var request = URLRequest(url:downloadURL)
                request.httpMethod = "HEAD"
                
                let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                        
                        let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? -1
                        let errorDescription = (response as? HTTPURLResponse).debugDescription
                        var errorMsg = "Download URL not reachable. httpResponse.statusCode: (\(statusCode)). -> URL(\(request.url?.absoluteString ?? "missing url"))"
                        errorMsg += " ->  Response: \(errorDescription)"
                        
                        Console.sharedInstance.log.error(errorMsg)
                        Tracker.sharedInstance.trackEvent(withName: "ERROR", eventParameters: ["error": errorMsg])
                        
                        Async.main {
                            completion(nil, error ?? NSError(domain: "com.xxx.app", code: statusCode, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: errorMsg]))
                        }
                        
                        return
                    }
                    
                    Async.main {
                        completion(downloadURL, nil)
                    }
                }
                
                task.resume()
            }
        })
        
        return uploadTask
    }
```

Comment: I think you have enabled app-check on your firebase storage service, and your app check token is currently invalid. Can you confirm that you have an **[Initialized App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/app-attest-provider?authuser=0#initialize).** If yes then you just need to refresh the token.

Comment: Yes I am using AppCheck in my project. If AppCheck was the problem, would it be possible to upload my file to Google Cloud?

Comment: Also AppCheck.appCheck().isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled returns true

Comment: How did you solve this?